# NodeJS + MySql and large concurrent access

Tags: mysql, node.js

So I have been writting this NodeJS Quiz App. At first we are not expecting that much users, but as time goes by we are looking at about ~50000 potential registered users.
Considering the DB of choice iss MySql, and also considering not all registered users are going to be logged in at the same time, what is the maximum number of concurrent MySQL connections possible? 
Also, how much RAM and CPU would I need to host this app?

Comment: That highly depends on how well you have written your application. But the number of logged in or currently active users it not equal to concurrent connections your system needs. An action the user performs should ideally not take more than some milliseconds (ideally not even a millisecond), so with 50 connection you should be able to handle a really large amount of active users.

Comment: With information from SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; and use of mysqlcalculator.com, in 10 minutes, you could have a reasonable estimate of RAM needed, just by changing max_connections, even to 10000000 which at all defaults, is 27TB.  How deep are your pockets?

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server performance tuning analysis.

Comment: @Wilson Hauck: Please check Eric Wong's answer. As you can see 50000 registered users and 50000 concurrent connections are not quite the same. And, as I learned from the right answers, a technique called 'pooling' will solve my problem smoothly with less than 2Gb RAM.

Comment: Registered users means nothing, since at any point in time 2 / 3 of those people will be asleep and not using your site.  Would still like to analyze your posted data, when available.  Thanks

Comment: Please read carefully my question: "...considering  **bold  ...not all registered users are going to be logged in** at the same time".
If you bother to know, instead of keeping digressing over semantics, the correct answer would be 'connection pooling'.

Comment: That would be correct.  Different versions have different terms for the Global Variables to be used to engage 'connection pooling'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using node.js, you can simply use connection pooling, there is no obvious downside to pooling but you are establishing much less connection (and less overhead).

In addition, it all goes down to how much query is actually executed and how much execution time they need, here are some make up numbers:

Let's say if 50k users all go online at the same time, and each user makes 1 interaction per 5s and takes 10ms DB time to execute, then 50k * 10ms / 5s = 100 concurrent connection needed.

Of course you need to factor in some real numbers, and read-to-write ratio matters a lot (read can potentially run in parallel), and cache can help a lot if reading makes up large number of queries.

All in all, you are unlikely to need much if all you do is some simple select and insert per interaction.

PS [This post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52183/how-much-ram-is-required-for-5000-concurrent-users-mysql) gave some interesting number: with connection pooling, 5k connection = 100k concurrent user. Of course he/she didn't mention his/her load type, but you can see that (concurrent / connection threads) can be up to tens and hundred when connection pool is in place.

Comment: Turns out your math makes sense mr Wong. I really won't need that much RAM to manage thousands of connections performing SELECT, mostly. And thanks for mentioning connection pooling, because it seems to be the right way to go. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you can set mySQL the max global connection up to 10,00,000.
and for hardware requirement below link can help you.

https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/02/25/mysql-challenge-100k-connections/

Hope you get your answers if not let me know.